# IPFS streams not buffers

Tags: node.js, typescript, ipfs, fastify

I'm trying to create an API get URL that can be called with `<img src='...'/>` that will actually load the image from IPFS.

I'm getting the file from IPFS and I can send it as a buffer via fastify but can't send it as a stream.

here's the working buffer using `ipfs.cat`

```
import { concat as uint8ArrayConcat } from "uint8arrays/concat";
import all from "it-all";

  fastify.get(
    "/v1/files/:username/:cid",
    async function (request: any, reply: any) {
      const { cid }: { cid: string } = request.params;
      const ipfs = create();
      const data = uint8ArrayConcat(await all(ipfs.cat(cid)));
      reply.type("image/png").send(data);
    }
  );
```

Docs for [ipfs cat](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/docs/core-api/FILES.md#ipfscatipfspath-options)
Docs for [fastify reply buffers](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Reply/#buffers)

I also tried sending it as a stream to try and not load the file into the server's memory...

```
  import { concat as uint8ArrayConcat } from "uint8arrays/concat";
  import all from "it-all";
  import { Readable } from "stream";
  ...

  fastify.get(
    "/v1/files/:username/:cid",
    async function (request: any, reply: any) {
      const { cid }: { cid: string } = request.params;
      const ipfs = create();
      
      const bufferToStream = async (buffer: any) => {
        const readable = new Readable({
          read() {
            this.push(buffer);
            this.push(null);
          },
        });
        return readable;
      };

      const data = uint8ArrayConcat(await all(ipfs.cat(cid)));
      const str = await bufferToStream(data);
      reply.send(str);
    }
  );
```

With a new error

```
 Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
```

Here I'm trying to push into the stream

```
  import { concat as uint8ArrayConcat } from "uint8arrays/concat";
  import all from "it-all";
  import { Readable } from "stream";

  fastify.get(
    "/v1/files/:username/:cid",
    async function (request: any, reply: any) {
      const { cid }: { cid: string } = request.params;
      const ipfs = create();

      const myStream = new Readable();
      myStream._read = () => {};

      const pushChunks = async () => {
        for await (const chunk of ipfs.cat(cid)) {
          myStream.push(chunk);
        }
      };
      pushChunks();
      reply.send(myStream);
    }
  );
```

the error now is

```
INFO (9617): stream closed prematurely
```

and trying to dump it all in the stream

```
  import { concat as uint8ArrayConcat } from "uint8arrays/concat";
  import all from "it-all";
  import { Readable } from "stream";

  fastify.get(
    "/v1/files/:username/:cid",
    async function (request: any, reply: any) {
      const { cid }: { cid: string } = request.params;
      const ipfs = create();
      var myStream = new Readable();
      myStream._read = () => {};
      myStream.push(uint8ArrayConcat(await all(ipfs.cat(cid))));
      myStream.push(null);
      reply.send(myStream);
    }
  );
```

with error

```
 WARN (14295): response terminated with an error with headers already sent
```

Is there any benefit to converting it to a stream? Hasn't IPFs already loaded it into memory??

Comment: `Should I be sending a buffer or a stream?` the buffer loads all into the server's memory, the stream does not

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon as ipfs.cat() returns a buffer, does that mean it's already in the server's memory? Would returning the buffer from IPFS via fastify load it into memory twice?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any benefit to converting it to a stream? Hasn't IPFs already loaded it into memory??

The ipfs module returns many `chunks` as a byte array.
So a file is the sum of these `chunks`.
Now, if you push all these chunks into an Array, and then `uint8ArrayConcat` is called, all the `chunks` are actually in your memory server.
So, if the file is 10 GB, your server has an array of bytes equal to 10 GB in memory.

Since this is unwanted for sure, you should push every chunk from the ipfs file to the response. By doing this, the `chunk` buffer array is transitive in the server's memory, but it is not persisted. So, in this case, you will not have the 10 GB file in memory, but only a tiny slice of it.

Since ipfs.cap returns an Async iterator, you could handle manually or use something like [`async-iterator-to-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-iterator-to-stream) to write:

```js
const ipfsStream = asyncIteratorToStream(ipfs.cat(cid))
return reply.send(ipfsStream)
```

As follow up, I share this awesome resource about [node.js stream and buffers](https://github.com/lmammino/streams-workshop/blob/master/01-buffer-vs-stream/README.md)